# python serialize string

Tags: python, serialization

I am needing to unserialize a string into an array in python just like php and then serialize it back.

Comment: this is what I am getting?

File "serv.py", line 8, in ?
    zin_arr = pickle.loads(zin)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/pickle.py", line 1393, in loads
    file = StringIO(str)
TypeError: expected read buffer, tuple found

Comment: @David that means your "zin" is a tuple, not a string. You should check to see what "zin" actually is.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean PHP's explode, try this

```
>>> list("foobar")
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']

>>> ''.join(['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r'])
'foobar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [pickle module](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). It is probably what you're looking for.

```
import pickle

# Unserialize the string to an array
my_array = pickle.loads(serialized_data)

# Serialized back
serialized_data = pickle.dumps(my_array)
```

Comment: Hmm Maybe he did... not enough detail to know!

Answer (score 0):

What "serialized" the data in question into the string in the first place?  Do you really mean an [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) (and if so, of what simple type?), or do you actually mean a [list](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange) (and if so, what are the list's items supposed to be?)... etc, etc...

From the OP's comments it looks like he has `zin`, a `tuple`, and is trying to treat it as if it was, instead, a `str` into which data was serialized by pickling. So he's trying to unserialize the tuple via `pickle.loads`, and obviously that can't work -- `pickle.loads` wants an `str` (that's what the `s` MEANS), **NOT** a tuple -- it can't work with a tuple, it has even no idea of what to DO with a tuple.

Of course, neither do we, having been given zero indication about where that tuple comes from, why is it supposed to be a string instead, etc, etc.  The OP should edit his answer to show more code (how is `zin` procured or fetched) and especially the code where `zin` is supposed to be PRODUCED (via `pickle.dumps`, I imagine) and how the communication from the producer to this would-be consumer is happening (or failing to happen;-).

Answer (score 0):

A string is already a sequence type in Python. You can iterate over the string one character at a time like this:

```
for char in somestring:
    do_something(char)
```

The question is... what did you want to do with it? Maybe we can give more details with a more detailed question.